# Registering hibernate event listeners to annotated entities at runtime

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-4.x, event-listener

I want to register event listener to some entities that I choose at runtime .

I created an annotation named @LocalableEntity and getting annotated entities by google reflection api so I want to add event listener to them.

My code is here ;

```
@Component
public class HibernateEventWiring {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
private LocalizationListener listener;

@PostConstruct
public void registerListeners() {

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");
    EventListenerRegistry registry = ((SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory).
                                       getServiceRegistry().
                                       getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);


     Set<Class<?>> annotated =  reflections.
                                getTypesAnnotatedWith(LocalableEntity.class);

     for(Class<?> clazz : annotated) {

         // I want to add listener to these annotated classses

     }

    // this code line registering listener for all entities
    registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PRE_LOAD).appendListener(listener);


    }  
}
```

So , how can I do that ?